# Why WooCoomerce add a hooked element twice?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I created a snipped to display custom content when a specific variation from a subscription is in cart. This works perfectly fine! But I have some problems with the selected hook. I want to display it on the checkout page. And it adds it twice! But I don't know why.. why is that hook fired 2 times?

Here is a screenshot: https://ibb.co/dQf8tsZ

**This is my code** - (When I use another hook it only displays it once.)

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping', 'check_if_variation_is_in_cart', 10, 0 );

function check_if_variation_is_in_cart() {

$variable_product_id = 15340;

if( in_array( $variable_product_id, array_column( WC()->cart->get_cart(), 'product_id' ) ) ) {
    
    echo '<div class="cbc-abo-monthly">';
    echo '<h3 class="cbc-abo-monthly-header">' . __( 'Info', 'woocommerce' ) . ' </h3>';
    echo '<p>' . __( 'This is a subscription', 'woocommerce' ) . ' </p>';
    echo '</div>';
    
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not unusual for hooks to fire multiple times.

Comment: https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_review_order_before_shipping - check "Where the hook is called" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that this plugin will help you out troubleshooting this issue and find the reason why this hook is triggered twice: https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/

You will be able to monitor all of the hooks and queries to your database, which should be more than enough to find why.